# What kind of spider is this and is it dangerous?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, species, arachnology

Found this spider on my couch the other day in Steubenville, Ohio. The spider is about 1 - 1.5'' (2.5 - 4 cm) long. The spider looks brownish in the image, but tends to a pale yellow color in reality.

[image]

Comment: It's not a [brown recluse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_recluse_spider), the pattern on the head and the shape of the abdomen are wrong.

Comment: That looks like a good ol' wolf spider.  Call him spiderbro and leave him to hunt down obnoxious insects.

Comment: It looks like a member of the Thomasidae (crab spiders) To properly identify spiders to genus or species I would have to see the eye pattern. It is harmless, Dangerous spiders in Steubenville are unlikely

Comment: its face would have helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice female Nursery Web Spider, related to the Fishing Spiders.  They're rather pretty animals, and like almost all spiders, quite harmless to anything that's too big to eat.  The very rectangular cephalothorax ('head' end) pattern and the simple wavy line down the abdomen are the key clues for this one.  They also like to sit with the front legs arranged in pairs.
https://bugguide.net/node/view/2919/bgimage

[image]